# grpc_python_plugin build is filing with latest version of grpc

Tags: grpc

I have used following command.

=============

```
-git clone https://github.com/grpc/grpc.git
-git submodule update --init
-make install prefix=/home/ubuntu/GRPC_LOCAL/latest_grpc/grpc/build/
```

===============

## Seeing following Error::

```
[CXX]     Compiling src/cpp/util/time.cc
[HOSTCXX] Compiling src/compiler/cpp_generator.cc
[HOSTCXX] Compiling src/compiler/csharp_generator.cc
In file included from src/compiler/csharp_generator.cc:40:0:
./src/compiler/csharp_generator.h:39:58: fatal error: google/protobuf/compiler/csharp/csharp_names.h: No such file or directory
 #include <google/protobuf/compiler/csharp/csharp_names.h>
                                                          ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [/home/ubuntu/GRPC_LOCAL/latest_grpc/grpc/objs/opt/src/compiler/csharp_generator.o] Error 1
ubuntu@ip-10-10-10-199:~/GRPC_LOCAL/latest_grpc/grpc$
```

============

Comment: This issue might be of relevance to you: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/7870 .

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you missed:

```
git submodule update --init
```

See here for instructions on building from source: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/src/cpp